# iMsg extension for existing iOS app

Tags: ios, xcode, imessage

I'm trying to attach iMsg extension to an existing iOS app. After running an extension from xCode, I'm getting an error saying:

> Could not locate installed application
>
> Install claimed to have succeeded, but application could not be found on device. bundleId = 'extension bundle id'

Extension appears in iMsg apps section, but I can't attach it for debug.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I changed 'Executable' in my scheme from actual extension to 'Ask on lunch' and issue disappeared