# Could not locate installed application Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode

I am trying to build share extension. Created the target, fixed the project settings (provisioning profile, app group, NSExtension).

Tried to run and saw the logs I added to the three methods `isContentValid`, `didSelectPost`, and `configurationItems`. This is my first time to create a share extension so, I was just looking around first and see when each method is called.

Now for some reason (I don't know what I did wrong), I am unable to see the logs from the extension. When I hit the run button in Xcode, the message `Finished running ...` gets displayed in the status bar on top.

Tried to change the scheme settings to the extension in the executable field, I get the following message when trying to run:

```
Could not locate installed application
Install claimed to have succeeded, but application could not be found on device. bundleId = <my-bundle-id-value>
```

Followed every solution I could find on the internet. Tried the solution from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37241579) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39705063).

**UPDATE**

I wanted to check if the extension actually runs or just the logs don't work. So I added the following logic to `isContentValid`:

```
- (BOOL)isContentValid {
    // Do validation of contentText and/or NSExtensionContext attachments here
    NSLog(@"isContentValid");
    NSUserDefaults * userDefaults = [[NSUserDefaults alloc] initWithSuiteName:@"<group-id>"];
    [userDefaults setObject:@"haha" forKey:@"key"];
    [userDefaults synchronize];
    return YES;
}
```

and read then read the `haha` in the main application it worked! So, the question is: Why can't I debug the application? Why doesn't the application print the log statements. Developing without logging and/or debugging could take 2x, if not more, time.

**UPDATE 2**

The best I was able to come up with is to manually attach the debugger to the extension, add breakpoints here and there (where I wanted to put logs) and edited the breakpoints to log as action and continue after evaluation.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33524051/how-to-debug-ios-share-extension

Comment: @MCMatan, have you read the second answer in the question you referred to?

Comment: yup, and I think it’s the same question